# show results in a Pivot way (no aggregate)

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

i've searched all over for an answer for this, and couldn't really find anything useful,
im pretty much a begginer in Sql so maybe i'm missing something basic

i have a simple table with 2 columns : line, fullname

this is the query i use :

```
SELECT 
    (select distributionline from extrasums where key=accounts.accountkey and SuFID='63') as 'line',
    fullname
 FROM 
    accounts
ORDER BY 
(select distributionline from extrasums where key=accounts.accountkey and SuFID='63'),
(select dotinline from extrasums where key=accounts.accountkey and SuFID='68')
```

these are the results i get :  (not allowed to embed images)

[image: results]

basically i get the distribution lines and the costumers, and the tables is ordered by the dist.lines and the place in line of each costumer.

all i want to do is show these results in a pivot-table style
i tried "pivot" but i understand you cant pivot without aggregate, because thats the whole point of "pivot" in sql.

this is what i want to achieve :

[image: goal]

basically the dist.lines are the column names and the results are orders in a pivot way

the dist.lines are not permanent, one day we can have 3 lines. the other we can have 10 lines. its dynamic based on the deliveries for tomorrow. obviously.
same with the costumers.

Comment: Posting sample data as text is more helpful than an image

Comment: Where does the set (43, 55, 68) come from? Is it dynamic?

Comment: Pivoting is a form of aggregation; you can't do it without it

Comment: Look up dynamic pivot on this site. It has been asked and answered dozens and dozens of times. It is NOT a simple thing so somebody who says they are new to sql is going to struggle with the implementation and the understanding.

Comment: SERG  - its dynamic. thats my problem

Answer (score 1):

you're welcome:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;

SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.LINE ORDER BY a.fullname) AS rownum, a.line, a.fullname
INTO #temp
FROM (   SELECT 43 AS line, 'Daniel' AS fullname
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 43 AS line, 'john' AS fullname
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 43 AS line, 'kenny' AS fullname
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 43 AS line, 'adam' AS fullname
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 55 AS line, 'james' AS fullname
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 55 AS line, 'jones' AS fullname
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 68 AS line, 'kelly' AS fullname) AS a;


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @colname AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @colname = STUFF((   SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.line) 
                         FROM #temp AS c
                         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                 , 1
                 , 1
                 , '');
SET @cols = STUFF((   SELECT DISTINCT ',ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(c.line) + ','''') AS '+QUOTENAME(c.line )
                      FROM #temp AS c
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
              , 1
              , 1
              , '');

PRINT @cols
PRINT @colname

SET @query =
    N'SELECT rownum, ' + @cols
    + N' from 
            (
                select rownum
                    , fullname
                    , line
                from #temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(fullname)
                for line in (' + @colname + N')
            ) p ';
PRINT @query
EXECUTE (@query);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yynkr.png)

Comment: thats not really what im after

Comment: can you elaborate whats missing?

Comment: i want it to show without the "null" values and also i need the code to work automatically without me "union"ing the specific lines in the code everytime. or naming the specific dist.lines in the SELECT statement. because like i said .. its dynamic.

Comment: i wrote union as i dont have your table. You would need to replace it with your table and you would not need any unions then, if you don't want nulls use MAX(ISNULL(fullname,'')) and it will work as you wanted. all dynamic

Comment: -aruna
i tried like u said, 

i got this error :
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near '('.

i tried changing it to   MAX(ISNULL(fullname,''''))   as it is all writting  between ''
but still the same error,

also - will it replace the null to just empty fields? ? 
or get rid of them completly? 

the whole point of this query is to let our distribution manager see what are his deliveris for tommorow in a simple pivot screen 
there can be no empty squares or spaces nor "null"s

sorry for my english

Comment: @doomiloom in my solution i added code to remove nulls, you still need to change the soruce to your table but it would work now

Comment: thanks, im replying to you in a new "answer" so i can add a picture of the results i got..

Comment: @doomiloom I saw your printscreen. It helped to understand the problem. I fixed my solution. Check if it works now

Comment: ive tried it now. all i get is the message "(1 row affected)"  and no results are printed